# Problems with Python callback

Tags: python

I think I'm going about this the wrong way, am very new to Python so after a bit of advice. I have a program (or trying to) that connects to remote server gathers a bit of info and saves it. Prior to this the user enters the IP and presses connect. I have cut all the irrelevant stuff out and left the meat of it in.

```
def connect():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    #paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(ip.get(), username=username, password=password, timeout=5)
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        text_box.insert(INSERT,"Connection error: Unable to open a connection to ")

    #  Display  Connected in the gui:
    ip_con_status.delete(1.0, END)
    ip_con_status.insert(INSERT,"Connected")
    get_but.config(state=NORMAL)

def getinfo():
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls",  timeout=5)

    # Display the remote shell's GUI text output:
    info = stdout.read()
    text_box.insert(INSERT,info)


# Create window
masterwindow = Tk()
masterwindow.minsize(windowx,windowy)
masterwindow.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(windowx, windowy, windowxpos, windowypos))

# Create text window and attach scrollbar
tboxw = windowx-200
tboxh = windowy-200
scroll = Scrollbar(masterwindow)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

textfont = ('consolas', 10)
text_box = Text(masterwindow, wrap=WORD, height=22, width=141)

text_box.config(font=textfont)
text_box.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
text_box.place(x = 10, y = 40)
scroll.config(command=text_box.yview)

# Connect button
ip_y = ip_y+25
con_but = Button(masterwindow, text="Connect", state=DISABLED, padx=17, command=connect)
con_but.place(x = ip_x, y = ip_y)

# Get button
ip_y = ip_y+65
get_but = Button(masterwindow, text="Get", state=DISABLED, padx=20, command=getinfo)
get_but.place(x = ip_x, y = ip_y)
```

So why does the callback to 'getinfo' not work. I have to include again:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip.get(), username=username, password=password, timeout=5)
```

Thanks

Comment: So, what _is_ `ssh` in `getinfo`? Different functions have different local namespaces. If you want multiple functions to have the same object in their namespaces, you can make it global or pass it to them explicitly as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

ssh is only defined within the one function ... this is a good time to start learning about namespaces

```
def fn(a,b,c):
    x=a

fn(22,33,44)
# there is no X it only exists inside of fn
```

likewise

```
def connect():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    #paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect(ip.get(), username=username, password=password, timeout=5)
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        text_box.insert(INSERT,"Connection error: Unable to open a connection to ")

    #  Display  Connected in the gui:
    ip_con_status.delete(1.0, END)
    ip_con_status.insert(INSERT,"Connected")
    get_but.config(state=NORMAL)
```

only defines ssh inside of its function ...

you have a couple options

1. you can create a class to maintain state
2. you could have some global dictionary that contains state
3. you could add `global ssh` at the top of connect and also have `ssh=None` in the root level namespace